# Not able to click on an Element present in a PopUp window by VBA

Tags: jquery, vba, excel

Respected Expert, I am developing my below VBA code where I am Not able to click on an Element presents in a PopUp window via VBA.

```
Sub GoToWebsiteTest()
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim tags As Object
Dim tagx As Object
Dim repo As Object
Dim Element As HTMLButtonElement
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

i = 0
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "https://oneview.myurl.in/"
With appIE
    .navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

appIE.document.getElementById("Username").Value = "xxx"
appIE.document.getElementById("Password").Value = "xxxx"
i = InputBox("type")
appIE.document.getElementById("txtcaptcha").Value = i
Set tags = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each tagx In tags
If tagx.Type = "submit" Then
   tagx.Click
End If
Next

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
Set HTMLdoc = appIE.document
Set e = HTMLdoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_gridUser_ctl00_ctl04_lnkG2")
e.Click

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title

    If my_title Like "Back Office" & "*" Then
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Set HTMLdoc1 = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next
```

Till Here My code works totally Fine,please Help me out how can i handle the Popup window and click on the required element in the Popup window.I have Tried Below Code but its not working at all.

```
With HTMLdoc1
    .Visible = True
End With

Set f = HTMLdoc1.document.all.Item("Click to enter  Share Transactions")
f.Click

End Sub
```

I also Tried Below For each loop as well but fail to achieve my object.

```
Set f = HTMLdoc1.document.getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each ti In f
If ti.Title = "Click to enter  Share Transactions" Then
ti.Click
End If
Next
```

The HTML code For the same is as below:

```
<div class="topFolder" id="a2" title="Click to enter  Share Transactions" style="color: red; 
background: rgb(228, 246, 248); border-width: 1px 1px 0px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: rgb(228, 246, 248);
 border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(228, 246, 248); border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(228, 246, 248);
 border-bottom-style: initial; border-bottom-color: initial; padding-bottom: 3px;"><img class="icon" height="17" src="/cgi-bin/images/bl.gif"
 width="19"><nobr>Share Transactions</nobr></div>
```

[image]

Entered In to the Particular Frame

```
Dim iFrm As HTMLIFrame
Set iFrm = HTMLdoc1.document.frames("fraToc").document.getElementById("aMenu")
```

[image]

Entered In to the Particular Frame and click on the particular element

```
Dim iFrm As MSHTML.HTMLWindow2
Dim HTMLdocc As HTMLDocument

Set iFrm = HTMLdoc1.document.frames("fraToc").document.getElementById("aMenu")
Set iFrm2 = iFrm.getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each divi In iFrm2
If divi.ID = "a2" Then
divi.Click
End If
Next
```

[image]

Comment: If its every time id for this element  "a2" then i suppose you can do this document.getElementById("a2").click()

Comment: I have enter the code **HTMLdoc1.document.getElementById("a2").click()**  But showing compile error of **Expected:=** even I Have tried **f = HTMLdoc1.document.getElementById("a2") f.Click** But not working.

Comment: Ok, can  you give a real url ?

Comment: @IR_IR Sir, I can't share you the URL because then I will also have to share you the credentials,But Please find the HTML codes picture which I just update in my question.

Comment: Ok, you have a problem with framset and you can not have direct contact with this elements, that elements for you is "invisible", but you have solution you need to play with something like this Set HTMLDoc = ie.document.frames(x).document. i can not try this because i do not have similar web to do that.

Comment: @IR_IR Sir, As per your guidance I have enable my code to entered into my required Frame the same I have Updated in my question..Now please guide me further, how can I click my required element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135682/discussion-between-sagar-and-ir-ir).

Comment: @IR_IR Sir, Firstly I am so thankful for your help..I Have develop the code which enable macro to click into the required elements further I would just like your guidance, how can I access the Sub divisions of that particular element to click in that sub elements of it. I have Updated My code and the HTML codes as well in My question which will clear more about my query.. I am restricted to use the chat option therefore I am continue my further discussion via comment only..

Comment: if i understand correctly you want to iterate through child elements of div element?

Comment: Yes Sir Further child elements of div element. If you refer to my shared HTML snap As I derive till Id="a2",VBA Code for the same I have already updated in my question.Now I want to further iterate with child element for an example id="aPrepaid_Scheme_TOdocsSub" to click.

Comment: First off all, do you know before start anything every id of yours elements? If you do, than you need to create recursive function  for iterating through all frames in html, then the second recursive function for iterating through child and sub child elements.Then you need to call second function from first. You will with one command line iterate through all html document. This is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tsgXs/) for recursive function of child and sub child element its written in javascript but you will have picture

Comment: When I have time I could do VBA version of recursive functions for above purpose

Comment: @IR_IR Thank you so much sir, That will be really helpful.

Comment: Can you give me your mail please to send you excel file with code

Comment: @IR_IR Sir, My id - sagarsawant36@yahoo.in , sagarsawant528@gmail.com